# DateTimeFormat parsing error:Invalid format: "2018-04-02T21:57:05.091Z" is malformed at "T21:57:05.091Z"'

Tags: scala, datetime, elasticsearch, jodatime

I am getting the following error

> Invalid format: "2018-04-02T21:57:05.091Z" is malformed at "T21:57:05.091Z"' 
>   org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:945)

when I try to do GET on elastic search. 
I have defined Date format with (`"yyyy-MM-dd"`) while creating index for Elastic search. 
I am trying to parse the ts using

```
DateTime.parse(source.get("ts").get.asInstanceOf[String],
               DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"))
```

Comment: Seems to work fine: `scala> DateTime.parse("2018-04-02T21:57:05.091Z", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"))
res2: org.joda.time.DateTime = 2018-04-02T15:57:05.091-06:00`... are you sure the error is from that piece of code?

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). `Instant.parse( "2018-04-02T21:57:05.091Z" )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean "I have defined Date format with `("yyyy-MM-dd")`" when the example shows the pattern `("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSZ")`?

The latter works for me (and confirmed by Alvaro). The former gets the error indicated.  It appears the "forPattern" isn't the pattern getting utilised.

```
package gist;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String testString = "2018-04-02T21:57:05.091Z";

//      Works...
        String format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";

//      Fails with...
//      Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2018-04-02T21:57:05.091Z" is malformed at "T21:57:05.091Z"
//        String format = "yyyy-MM-dd";

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(format);
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(testString, formatter);
        System.out.println(dateTime);

    }
}
```